# ArrayList and String[] AND Object[]

Tags: java

I have searched this, but couldn't find what i need, so i created a new post. I hope to understand about this problem. Thanks.

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<String>();
arraylist.add("Nguyen");
arraylist.add("Viet");

String[] name={"Quan","Doan","Thi","Ha"};
arraylist.add(name);// error here 

ArrayList<Object> arraylist1=new ArrayList<Object>();
arraylist1.add("Nguyen");
arraylist1.add("Viet");
Object[] name1={"Quan","Doan","Thi","Ha"};
arraylist1.add(name1);// not error
```

Can someone explain that when i pass `name` into `add()` method then I get a error, but when i pass `name1` into `add()` method, it works fine, why is it so...

Comment: because an `Object[]` is an `Object`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`arraylist` is an ArrayList of String elements, so you can't add an array instance to it. `arraylist1` is an `ArrayList` of `Object` elements, so you can add an array to it, since an array is an `Object`.

If you wish to add the individual elements of the arrays to the `List`s, both `add` calls should be changed to `addAll` :

```
arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(name));
arraylist1.addAll(Arrays.asList(name1));
```

Answer (score 8):

```
arraylist.add(name);// error here
```

Error because `name` is an array. Not a `String`. You are trying to add a Array object to an ArrayList which accepts only Strings.

```
arraylist1.add(name1);// not error
```

No error because `name1` is an `Object` array. In Java *every class is an Object, even an array of Objects also an Object*. Hence it accepted it as an Object. Though your *name1* is an array of Objects, as a whole it is an Object itself first.

Comment: Does not every type instance in Java derive from `Object`? Are there any caveats where one could NOT add a referenced value to `arraylist1`?

Comment: @ShaunWilson Primitives does not derive from `Object`. You could still add them to `arrayList1` because they would be autoboxed, but they would not be primitives anymore. Also, the term `everything` is too large. An operator is not an object in java while it may be in other languages which causes the confusion.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard My bad.. should be `Every class`. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @ShaunWilson There is no caveats at all. You can add anytype of Object or Primitive to it.  If you see there are only Classes and primitives. Since the arraylist of type Object, you can add any classes object to it. Coming to primitive part, from Java 1.5 we have autoboxing/unboxing which automatically turns any primitive to its equivalent Wrapper class.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be thinking that when you do

```
String[] name={"Quan","Doan","Thi","Ha"};
arraylist.add(name);// error here
```

It is supposed to add all the elements of the array to the list. That's not true. The `add` method just adds the one parameter it is given to the list.

In the first case, that one element is an array of strings. An array of strings is not a string itself, so this fails.

In the second case, that one element is an array of objects. An array of objects is itself an object, and therefore it is added to the list. But note that the *array* is added, not the objects inside it.

Answer (score 5):

1st example throws an error because you declare an `ArrayList` of `Strings` but later try to add an `Array` of `Strings` (not a `String`, but a `collection` of `Strings`) to it.

2nd example works because you declare and `ArrayList` of `Objects` and later you add `Objects` to it (understand that everything in Java is an `Object`: a `String` is an `Object`, an `Array` also and for example a `Boolean` is an `Object` also, you can try adding `True` in the 2nd example and you will see that it will also work).

Answer (score 2):

Here i see some misunderstanding of `String` and `String[]` both are not same, while seeing your following code

```
String[] name={"Quan","Doan","Thi","Ha"};
arraylist.add(name);// error here
```

it seems like you are trying to add `String[]` object into `ArrayList` of type `String`. If you want to add `name` array into list then your list type must be `String[]`. So becasue type are different so you cannot add `String[]` object into list of type `String`. But When your have list of type `Object` then of course you can add any object into it.

Answer (score 1):

IDE tells us about object data type clearly.

**First code snippet**

```
In this error code snippet:
ArrayList<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<String>();
arraylist.add("Nguyen");
arraylist.add("Viet");
String[] name={"Quan","Doan","Thi","Ha"};
arraylist.add(name);
```

[image]
At line 6, object named `arraylist` has type `ArrayList<java.lang.String>`
but you try something like this: `ArrayList<java.lang.String[]>` cause an incompatibility data type error.

**Second code snippet**

```
ArrayList<Object> arraylist1=new ArrayList<Object>();
arraylist1.add("Nguyen");
arraylist1.add("Viet");
Object[] name1={"Quan","Doan","Thi","Ha"};
arraylist1.add(name1);
```

[image]
When step debug to line 10, `name1` is has data type `java.lang.Object`, `arraylist1` has datatype `ArrayList<Object>`. Therefore, add element `name1` to `arraylist1` success.